Expressing $1+\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^m\sum\limits_{n=k}^m\frac{S_{n-1}^{(k)}(-1)^{n+k}(-xn)^k}{n!}$ only in terms a sum over $k$.
Using an inversion theorem, one finds:
$$f(x)=\frac{\ln(1-x)}{\ln(x)}\implies f^{-1}(x)=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-xn)_{n-1}}{n!}$$
This is useful for integrating $f^{-1}(x)$ as it is given explicitly, but the Pochhammer symbol $(n)_m$ looks hard to integrate. On the other hand, it can be expanded with the Stirling numbers of the first kind making it easier to integrate:
$$f^{-1}(x)=1 + \lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{S_{n-1}^{(k)}(-1)^{n+k}(-xn)^k}{n!}=1+\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{n=k}^m\frac{S_{n-1}^{(k)}(-1)^{n+k}(-xn)^k}{n!}$$
The $m$th partial sums of both are equal, but $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=k}^m\frac{S_{n-1}^{(k)}(-1)^nn^k}{n!}$ seems to have no closed form and $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty\frac{S_{n-1}^{(k)}(-1)^nn^k}{n!}$ diverges.
On the other hand a Maclaurin series for $f^{-1}(x)$ may not be possible. Is there any way to express $f^{-1}(x)$ only in terms of the $k$ sum?
